# how displays classname for object?

Tags: python, oop

please help solve the problem. i create class and 2 objects:

```
class Raft(object):
  def __init__(self, peoples=3, speed=10, color='maroon', sails=1):
    self.peoples = peoples
    self.speed = speed
    self.color = color
    self.sails = sails
    Raft.quantity += 1

  quantity = 0

  def __str__(self):
    # return str(self.__dict__)
    return str(self.__name__)



raft1 = Raft(peoples=2, speed=10, color='yellow', sails=1)
raft2 = Raft(peoples=3, speed=5, color='maroon', sails=0)


print(raft1)
print(raft2)
```

but after run this script in console i get follow errormessage:

```
kalinin@kalinin ~/python/boats $ python index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(raft1)
  File "index.py", line 27, in __str__
    return str(self.__name__)
AttributeError: 'Raft' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

i need display classname for objects: raft1, raft2

Comment: Yes, there's no `self.__name__`. Use`type(self).__name__` or `self.__class__.__name__`.

Comment: thanks. it solve the problem